# An estimate in the introduction of the Hilbert transform in Grafakos's Classical Fourier Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In the introduction of the Hilbert transform on the Schwartz space, the following estimate is made in Grafakos's *[Classical Fourier Analysis](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9781441918550)* (3rd) (Section 5.1.1):

> [image]

**Question**: Would anyone explain how the second term in (5.1.2) is done?

---

It should come from the second term of (5.1.1) according to the discussion between the two formulas. But I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{\phi(x)}{x} dx=\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{x\phi(x)}{x^2} dx \le \sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|x\phi(x)|\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{1}{x^2} dx= 2\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|x\phi(x)|$$
since

$$\int_{|x|\ge 1}\frac{1}{x^2} dx= 2\int_{x\ge 1}\frac{1}{x^2} dx= 2\left[\frac{-1}{x}\right]^{\infty}_{1} =2$$